# Laravel <x-app-layout></x-app-layout> ruin css file and doesn't appear on some pages

Tags: php, laravel

i copied the tag  in my main page to get logout option but it doesnt show anythig and its ruin the page design

```
 @if(Route::has('login'))
                    @Auth
                    <x-app-layout>

                    </x-app-layout>
                    @else
                        <ul class="LogSignButtons">
                            <a href="{{route('login')}}"><button class="LogInButton">Log In</button></a>
                            <a href="{{route('register')}}"><button class="SignUpButton">Sign Up</button></a>
                        </ul>

                    @endauth
                    @endif
```

i tried to change css link to this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />` ==> it is only suitble for page design

Comment: You'll need to explain your problem a little better; I have no idea what this question is asking, and without an example of your expected outcome vs your actual outcome, I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to help you...

Comment: i made the front end first separately then wanted to connect it to the data base using the laravel framework, when i wanted to use the pre-made login/logout it didnt show up in my main page after loging in for once

Comment: u did npm install and npm run build , yes ?

Answer (score 0):

bro
I got the same issue like you.
I have tried some commands below and it works for me.

`composer require laravel/ui`

`php artisan ui bootstrap`

If still not work, you just remove bootstrap class.

Comment: NOTE on laravel 10, laravel/ui is deprecated, look at github.com/laravel/ui first note in readme ! Breeze/tailwind…